# Time required by some statements to execute not constant

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

Inside my SQLite `Adapter` class, for an Android application, I have the following method. The key `KEY_WAS` can be either 0 or 1. The method searches for a given `name` and a given `date` in the database (for a given date there can only be one unique entry for a particular name in the DB). So, if such an entry is present, we go inside `if`, otherwise `was` remains zero. Finally, `was` is returned.

```
public int wasHere(String name, String date) throws SQLException {
    Log.d("wasHere", "begins, date = " + date);
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_NAME
            + "=" + "'" + name + "'" + " AND " + KEY_DATE + "=" + "'"
            + date + "'", null, null, null, null);
    Log.d("wasHere", "below Cursor");
    int was = 0;
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("wasHere", "inside IF");
        was = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WAS));
    }
    Lod.d("wasHere", "ends");
    return was;
}
```

From the log entries, I am pasting some particular ones (you can ignore the time between "begins" and "ends" as that depends on the loop which is calling `wasHere`):

```
07-18 07:08:03.398: D/dbwas(29568): begins, date = 08 Aug 2013
07-18 07:08:03.398: D/dbwas(29568): below cursor
07-18 07:08:03.398: D/dbwas(29568): ends

07-18 07:08:03.398: D/dbwas(29568): begins, date = 09 Aug 2013
07-18 07:08:03.406: D/dbwas(29568): below cursor
07-18 07:08:03.406: D/dbwas(29568): ends

07-18 07:08:03.359: D/dbwas(29568): begins, date = 02 Aug 2013
07-18 07:08:03.359: D/dbwas(29568): below cursor
07-18 07:08:03.367: D/dbwas(29568): inside IF
07-18 07:08:03.367: D/dbwas(29568): ends

07-18 07:08:03.367: D/dbwas(29568): begins, date = 03 Aug 2013
07-18 07:08:03.367: D/dbwas(29568): below cursor
07-18 07:08:03.375: D/dbwas(29568): inside IF
07-18 07:08:03.375: D/dbwas(29568): ends

07-18 07:08:03.430: D/dbwas(29568): begins, date = 14 Aug 2013
07-18 07:08:03.430: D/dbwas(29568): below cursor
07-18 07:08:03.430: D/dbwas(29568): inside IF
07-18 07:08:03.430: D/dbwas(29568): ends
```

My question is regarding the log times for "begins" and "ends". As you can see above, among the five log entries, two (8 Aug and 14 Aug) take 0 time from "begins, date = ..." to "ends".

**9 Aug** takes 8 ms (.008 seconds) in executing the `Cursor` statement.

**2 Aug** and **3 Aug** take 8 ms (.008 seconds) in executing the `if` statement.

**14 Aug** takes no time is executing either of the two above mentioned statements.

Similarly, there are many such discrepancies in the "log". For different dates, the `Cursor` and `if` statements randomly take 8 ms (and yes, the time is always 8 ms).

Now, I am executing "wasHere" method hundreds of times, so hundreds of 8 milliseconds cost me too much time. Why are the above discrepancies happening randomly. And is there any way to remove it (or maybe another way of doing what I am doing). [8 Aug and 14 Aug statement take zero time as they should.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your system, the timer interrupt apparently runs at 125 Hz and thus happens every 8 ms.
If your function gets executed completely between two timer interrupts, you will see no change in the timestamps, but if a timer interrupt happens while your function is executing, you will see a jump of 8 ms.

There is no discrepancy in the *actual* execution times; the timestamps in your log are just not precise enough.

Comment: @BornAgain And to answer the question you did not ask: `CREATE INDEX blabla ON MyTable(date, name)`